# Problem with removing plugin action

Tags: plugins, actions

in my `functions.php` I try to remove an action from a plugin class. See both codes below. the remove doesn't work, but when I comment out the `add_action` (line 39) in the plugin class, then it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
function remove_trusted_theme_for_wholesale_customers() {
remove_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 
array('WC_GZD_Trusted_Shops_Template_Hooks','template_thankyou'), 10);
};
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_trusted_theme_for_wholesale_customers' );
```

Here is the plugin:

```
<?php

class WC_GZD_Trusted_Shops_Template_Hooks {

    protected static $_instance = null;

    public $base = null;

    public static function instance( $base ) {
        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) )
            self::$_instance = new self( $base );
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    private function __construct( $base ) {

        $this->base = $base;

        // Template actions
        if ( $this->base->is_enabled() )
            add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this, 'template_hooks' ), 13 );

        if ( $this->base->is_product_reviews_enabled() ) {
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array( $this, 'remove_review_tab' ), 40, 1 );
        }

        if ( $this->base->is_product_sticker_enabled() ) {
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array( $this, 'review_tab' ), 50, 1 );
        }

        if ( $this->base->is_product_widget_enabled() ) {
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_gzd_template_name', array( $this, 'set_product_widget_template' ), 50, 1 );
        }

    }

    public function template_hooks() {

        add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( $this, 'template_thankyou' ), 10, 1 );
        add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'template_trustbadge' ), PHP_INT_MAX );

    }

    public function set_product_widget_template( $template ) {

        if ( in_array( $template, array( 'single-product/rating.php' ) ) )
            $template = 'trusted-shops/product-widget.php';

        return $template;

    }

    public function remove_review_tab( $tabs ) {

        if ( isset( $tabs[ 'reviews' ] ) )
            unset( $tabs[ 'reviews' ] );
        return $tabs;

    }

    public function review_tab( $tabs ) {
        $tabs[ 'trusted_shops_reviews' ] = array(
            'title' => _x( 'Reviews', 'trusted-shops', 'woocommerce-germanized' ),
            'priority' => 30,
            'callback' => array( $this, 'template_product_sticker' ),
        );
        return $tabs;
    }

    public function template_product_sticker( $template ) {
        wc_get_template( 'trusted-shops/product-sticker.php' );
    }

    public function template_trustbadge() {
        wc_get_template( 'trusted-shops/trustbadge.php' );
    }

    public function template_thankyou( $order_id ) {
        wc_get_template( 'trusted-shops/thankyou.php', array(
            'order_id' => $order_id,
            'gtin_attribute' => $this->base->gtin_attribute,
            'brand_attribute' => $this->base->brand_attribute,
            'mpn_attribute' => $this->base->mpn_attribute,
        ) );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing will only remove an action added in a static method of class.

From https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

If an action has been added from within a class, for example by a plugin, removing it will require accessing the class *through a variable that holds the class instance*.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_my_class_action' );
function remove_my_class_action(){
  global $my_class;
  remove_action( 'wp_footer', array( $my_class, 'class_function_being_removed' ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so it is `function remove_trusted_theme_for_wholesale_customers() {
 global $my_class;
 remove_action('woocommerce_thankyou', array($my_class,'WC_GZD_Trusted_Shops_Template_Hooks::template_thankyou'), 10);
};
add_action( 'init', 'remove_trusted_theme_for_wholesale_customers' );` ?

Comment: you need an instance of the class WC_GZD_Trusted_Shops_Template_Hooks.  You should be able to get an instance by using $myInstance = WC_GZD_Trusted_Shops_Template_Hooks::instance() and then do remove_action('woocommerce_thankyou', array($myInstance, 'template_thankyou', 10);  It's also possible that may need to prioritize the removal of the action to a hook that occurs after the action is added.